# How can I use dynamic redirect urls in slack oAuth redirect url?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

I have a web page that requires a document id. I used slack authentication for the authentication. (because the web page is requesting from the slack channel). Slack requires redirect URL. So how can I put this dynamic redirect URL in slack?

The URL is => http://localhost:3000/document/
I tried to put it like this => http://localhost:3000/document/<>
but it did not work.

My code looks like this:

```
router.get('/res', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.query.code);
    var url = 'https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?code='+req.query.code+'&client_id=<the client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/document/25/';

    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            res.send(response.data);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error');
        });
});
```

I want to get 25th document after the authentication in the code. This 25 value is the dynamic value.

this was what I tried: http://localhost:3000/document/<>

[image]

Comment: can you show some code. what have you tried

Comment: redirect url is the url to be redirected after authentication,  I don't think it is possible to give a changing parameter as part of the redirect URL

Comment: @Hrishi ohh. is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not specify dynamic parameters on your OAuth redirect URL.

But you can still redirect the user to a dynamic URL after authentication. Instead of putting the document ID in the URL, put it in the current server session. Then once the request returns from Slack to your app just get the document ID from the current session and redirect the user.

Should be straight forward since you need to use server sessions anyways to verify the OAuth `state` for security purposes.